# Remix.run blog tutorial - optimistic UI

Tags: remix, remix.run

I'm following the blog tutorial on the [remix.run](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/tutorials/blog#homework) example page and I'm struggling with the Optimistic UI aspect of it and failing to find any examples online

As you can see in my [github repo](https://github.com/webknit/remix-blog-tutorial/blob/main/app/routes/posts/admin/new.tsx#L70) I am trying to render the `<PostAdmin />` route, but it's not loading for some reason.

```
import PostAdmin from "~/routes/posts/admin";

export default function NewPost() {
  const errors = useActionData();

  const transition = useTransition();
  const isCreating = Boolean(transition.submission);
  const title = transition?.submission?.formData?.get("title");

  return isCreating ? (
    <>
      <PostAdmin />
    </>
  ) : (
....
```

My original plan was to pass some additional items in here so I can render to the sidebar optimistically like the following. However I can't get the PostAdmin route to load at all, with the error `Cannot destructure property 'posts' of 'useLoaderData(...)' as it is undefined.`

```
export default function PostAdmin({
  newPost,
}: {
  newPost?: { title: string; slug: string };
}) {
```

As a side note, it's rendering the nested [AdminIndex](https://github.com/webknit/remix-blog-tutorial/blob/main/app/routes/posts/admin/new.tsx#L6) ok when I try that, but this would not achieve the homework example in the remix tasks as I need to pass it to the sidebar.

Hard one to explain and I imagine someone who's done the tasks before or has a solid example of Remix will understand. It may be that I am approaching this incorrectly. I have struggled to find complete examples anywhere.

Comment: Is that a private repo, because it doesn't exist? Also, is PostAdmin a route or a component, because it looks like you are trying to use it as component?

Comment: Apoligies @Kiliman, please try again it was private.
PostAdmin is a route (perhaps I am doing this wrong?) As mentioned though, the AdminIndex Router works fine, but the parent one does not.

Comment: I checked out your repo. It is a route, but you're trying to use it like a component (like @Kiliman said). Remix uses file-based routing, so to define a new route module, all you have to do is create the file (https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/tutorials/jokes#routes). Remix uses react-router under the hood to handle the route, which includes loading the data. So using it in the way you are won't work. Are you trying to display some type of loading screen when it's creating the post?

Comment: I am trying to do the "Optimistic UI" task which is in the homework section here @intrepid_em (https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/tutorials/blog#homework)
I need to render the sidebar with the data before it's inserted into the DB - "So your homework is to make it so when you hit "Create" it renders the post in the left nav and renders the "Create a New Post" link (or if you add update/delete do it for those too)."